# How to enable "New Folder" button in windows explorer for FTP - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, ftp

I have ftp acccount with read/write permission.

Connected to ftp server using windows explorer (windows 10).

I can create new folder using <kbd>Right Click</kbd> + <kbd>New</kbd> + <kbd>Folder</kbd>

But the "New folder" button is disable in windows explorer.

How to enable that button?

[image]

Comment: In the screenshot it doesn’t appear like you are logged in as a user hence the “Login as..” option.  Is that correct or is that option e displayed so you change which user your logged in as?

Comment: @Ramhound I already logged in. I tried login again using that "Login as" button, and successfully logged in but that the "New Folder" button kept disabled. I have only one account, no other username to change. I can create folder, copy paste new file, rename... ok to ftp server with that account.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Shift+N work?

Comment: @Moab `Ctrl+Shift+N` do not work. I can only create new folder by Right Click + "New" + "Folder" as in image in question, or copy/cut a folder from other folder to it.