# Remove or reduce size of the search bar in Windows 10 Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I don't know what exactly caused this, but a recent update to Windows 10 has made the Explorer search bar excessively wide, causing the folder path bar to shrink and not show the entire path.

Here's a screenshot of the explorer from a [6-month old question](https://superuser.com/questions/1482143/how-to-enable-new-folder-button-in-windows-explorer-for-ftp-windows-10):

[image]

And here's what mine look like:
[image]

For more reference, here's [one from 11 days ago](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZMLE.jpg). The search bar in mine is obnoxiously large. Is there any potential to fix this, possibly remove the update that caused it?

Comment: The ribbon size (relative to the rest of the app screen) is fixed and not changeable.

Comment: Type *winver* in the search bar and show the full version. Also, in Windows Update, review update history. Without relevant info, it's hard to be of help.

Comment: The search bar horizontal size can be changed by grabbing the space between the search bar and the reload button left of it (considering your screenshot). Move the mouse into this area to find the correct spot (the cursor will change to a left-right arrow).

Comment: You can click/drag the space between the search and the path, just hover your mouse in the space between and resize. It should save your preference in the registry (although I don't know where).

Comment: @Robert That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## Use mouse to move border

The search bar horizontal size can be changed by grabbing the space between the search bar and the reload button left of it (see the screenshot below). Move the mouse into this area to find the correct spot (the cursor will change to a left-right arrow).

[image]

In case the width change is not persistent you should do this:

1. Open task manager, go to the details tab.
2. Switch to an Explorer instance and make the width change.
   3  Switch back to task manager and and kill all `Explorer.exe` instances. This will also kill the desktop view.
3. To get back the desktop in Taskmanager open the `File`  menu and select `Execute new task`. In the new dialog then type `explorer` and press the OK button.

On my Windows 10 system the with seem to be stored in the `REG_BINARY` registry entry `HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\NavBar`.

By deleting or renaming it Windows restores the default size of the search window, next time you open a new Explorer instance.

Comment: The answer that _I_ am really looking for is whether it's possible to fix that new position (presumably by modifying the registry, if possible at all). Explorer seems to reset the search bar to its wide self with every restart.

Comment: @mgr326639 For me it works without problems. Just make sure before resizing the search bar horizontal size that all Explorer windows are closed! Otherwise the window that is last closed set's the new size and may override your changes.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks.  Everytime I manually adjusted the width, never knew that search bar width can be permanently saved.

Comment: Thank you so much @Robert for this answer and clarifying comment! This has been driving me crazy for ages

Comment: This does not appear to be permanent. I'll close all instances, resize, close, reopen, all looks good. Then Windows resets it. I don't know if it's reboots, updates, or just docking and undocking, using different displays in office vs home, or what, but it always ends up being freaking massive again.